# Android - AdMob is freezing the screen in every 10 seconds

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I'm using a banner adView in my app with firebase 11.0.2. I don't know if you've noticed that the AdMob is running something on the main thread and may freezing the screen every 10 seconds.

After running a method tracing, I found there's a "com.google.android.gms.ads.appcontent.h.run" method which gets called every 10 seconds. And it's running on the main thread. If the app is running on a high-end device then nothing should be worried about. Because the task may only takes 5ms or less to finish it. But if it's not, then it could take 100 ms or more to finish the task.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

It seems like this task is launched after the first refreshing of the ad.
What does this method do?
Is there a way to stop this task?
Is it really necessary?
If this is a method for retrieving view states, why don't they provide a API to let us update the view states?